# When does a quasicoherent sheaf vanish?

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $F$ be a quasi-coherent sheaf on a scheme $X$.  To check that $F$ vanishes it suffices to check that all the stalks of $F$ vanish.  I would like to know whether it suffices to check that all the fibers of $F$ vanish.

(I think I am using standard terms: the tensor product over $O_X$ with the local ring at $x$ is the stalk, and the tensor product over $O_X$ with the residue field at $x$ is the fiber.)

It suffices to answer the question on an affine scheme.  Let $R$ be a commutative ring.  For each prime ideal $p$ of $R$ let $k(p)$ be the residue field of the local ring $R_p$.  Let $M$ be an $R$-module, and suppose that $\mathrm{Tor}_i(k(p),M) = 0$ for all $i$ and all $p$.  (Tor taken in the category of $R$-modules).  Does it follow that $M = 0$?

If $M$ is finitely generated, the answer is yes.  In that case $M$ vanishes even when $\mathrm{Tor}_0(k(p),M) = 0$ for all maximal $p$, by Nakayama's lemma.  My question is whether there is a good replacement for Nakayama's lemma when $M$ is not finitely generated.

Comment: I believe something similar will hold if M is simple.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the scheme is locally noetherian, this is true and can be proved by noetherian induction. In fact, you can even replace $M$ with an object of bounded derived quasi-coherent category, if you are interested in such things.

The proof is relatively straightforward: For a complex of modules $M$ over the ring $R$, we may assume that any non-zero $f\in R$ acts by a quasi-isomorphism $f:M\to M$ (by the induction hypothesis), and then the cohomology of $M$ are defined over the field of fractions of $M$.

Comment: Wonderful.  Is this a famous argument, or off the top of your head?

Comment: I suspect that this is well known. If so, I would like references; the only one I know is Lemma 10 in Arinkin, Orthogonality of natural sheaves on moduli stacks of SL(2)-bundles with connections on P^1 minus 4 points.

Comment: Does this mean the statement is true in the non-derived setting if we assume $M$ to be flat?

Answer (score 5):

What about $R=\mathbb Z$ and $M=\mathbb Q/\mathbb Z$ ? All fibers are zero.

Comment: You'll notice he has _derived_ fibers. Those are non-zero in your example.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I only answered the first part of the question. 